# Python code for Bluetooth throws error after I had to reset the adapter

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluez, pybluez

I was trying out bluetooth programming in python. It was working fine till yesterday. This morning, there was a power outage and for some reason, the bluetooth module got disabled and it could not be turned on. So, I did a `sudo hciconfig hci0 reset` and then turned it on. From that point onwards, the simplest of the programs are failing to execute. Take [this one](https://code.google.com/p/pybluez/issues/attachmentText?id=53&aid=530000001&name=RFCOMM+Server.py&token=vnVPKroCQumF9hq0AwD6ea74DyE%3A1327666192157) for example. It gets stuck at `advertise_service` in `bluetooth` module and throws the following error (FYI: virtualenv was not a problem here. The systemwide python also does the same thing).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bt.py", line 17, in <module>
    advertise_service( server_sock, "SampleServer", service_id = uuid, service_classes = [ uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ], profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ])
  File "/home/machinename/.virtualenvs/py27/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 242, in advertise_service
    raise BluetoothError (str (e))
bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (2, 'No such file or directory')
```

Sometimes I got a different error when I compiled and reinstalled `Bluez` driver:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/bluetooth/bluez.py", line 268, in advertise_service
  bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: error no advertisable device.
```

But all of these worked like a charm before in that machine; in fact all of the program works just fine with my other ubuntu (14.04LTS) machine as I write this. I inspected the source code, and traced to a `_bluetooth.so` file - which is a compiled code, hence I couldn't figure out what to do anymore.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I traced root of the second error to [here](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/647198b994ce3458384b8680e68e368d85fbfd0e/bluez/btmodule.c#L2666)

Comment: Do the standard `hci` command line tools still work? Like `hcitool scan`?

Comment: Yes, the standard `hci` commands were working alright. Only the functions, which were being called from the [`_bluetooth`](https://github.com/karulis/pybluez/blob/master/bluetooth/bluez.py#L6) module, were throwing errors. If my code didn't refer to that module, everything was working fine.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**This error is due to incompatibility issues with BlueZ 5 and SDP with `bluetoothd`**

### Fix for 15.10 and BlueZ 5

Make sure, running `sdptool browse local` gives following error:

```
Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: No such file or directory
```

As it turns out, the culprit is `bluetoothd`, the Bluetooth daemon. Using SDP with `bluetoothd` requires deprecated features for some silly reason, so to fix this, the daemon must be started in compatibility mode with `bluetoothd -C` (or `bluetooth --compat`).

Find location of `bluetooth.service` by:

```
systemctl status bluetooth.service
```

Then edit `bluetooth.service` and look for

```
ExecStart=/usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

Append `--compat` at the end of this line, save, and then run

```
service bluetooth start
```

If all goes well, you should be able to successfully run

```
sudo sdptool browse local
```

Finally, reset the adapter:

```
sudo hciconfig -a hci0 reset
```

Things should work fine now

### Old answer

Just to let people know, I believe the latest [`BlueZ`](http://www.bluez.org/) build was somehow broken in my system. I downloaded, compiled and installed the [5.35](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.35.tar.xz) version, and nothing was working. I dialed down to [5.34](http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/bluetooth/bluez-5.34.tar.xz), still same. I also noticed that the bluetooth adapter was going down automatically 3-4 minutes after enabling it using,

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up # hci0 is the bt adapter
```

I used one usb bluetooth dongle to test. It did not go down automatically like the inbuilt adapter, but the problems persisted. Then I used `apt-get` to reinstall `bluez`,

```
apt-get install --reinstall bluez
```

and all of a sudden everything came back to normal.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. pybluez has not been ported to bluez5. There have been major API changes between bluez4 and bluez5. I think you'll find that your apt-get installs bluez4.

Comment: This link http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/41776/failed-to-connect-to-sdp-server-on-ffffff000000-no-such-file-or-directory worked for me

Answer (score 1):

To fix:

> bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (2, 'No such file or directory')

You need to:

1. `sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service`
2. Change from: `ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd`
3. To: `ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat`
4. `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Answer (score 0):

Again, as sidmeister mentioned,
Make sure, running sdptool browse local gives following error:

Failed to connect to SDP server on `FF:FF:FF:00:00:00:` No such file or directory

But,for those who are using initd system manager, its hard to find a solution if you want to execute `sdp_rfcomm_server/client` model and the terminal will keep on showing same error again and again. 
So for `init.d` follow these steps:

1. Stop bluetooth first

   $ /etc/init.d/bluetooth stop
2. Status check

   $ /etc/init.d/bluetooth status
3. Run bluetooth in compatibility mode(don't forget ampersand,otherwise prompt won't turn up )

   $ /usr/libexec/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat&
4. start bluetooth again

   $ /etc/init.d/bluetooth start
5. again try sdpbrowse

   $ sdptool browse local

Things should work for you now.

Comment: I wasted 6 hours trying to get it to work and your solution did the magic. Thanks a lot!