# bluetooth error no advertisable device

Tags: android, python, sockets, bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import bluetooth
import uuid

server_socket = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )

port = 1
server_socket.bind(("",port))
server_socket.listen(1)

uuID = ##generated uuid

bluetooth.advertise_service( server_socket, "test", service_id=uuID )

client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
print(client_socket)
print(client_address)
```

If anyone could help with this, that would be great.  I've tried going through the instructions listed here about 5 times: [Python code for Bluetooth throws error after I had to reset the adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33110992/python-code-for-bluetooth-throws-error-after-i-had-to-reset-the-adapter)

I keep getting an error saying "bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: error no advertisable device"  The line number points to the advertise_service line, and it does so whether or not I add the additional parameters as shown in the example in the pybluez github page, or bind the port to bluetooth.PORT_ANY
The method being called is here:

```
def advertise_service (sock, name, service_id = "", service_classes = [], \
        profiles = [], provider = "", description = "", protocols = []):
    if service_id != "" and not is_valid_uuid (service_id):
         raise ValueError ("invalid UUID specified for service_id")
    for uuid in service_classes:
        if not is_valid_uuid (uuid):
            raise ValueError ("invalid UUID specified in service_classes")
    for uuid, version in profiles:
        if not is_valid_uuid (uuid) or  version < 0 or  version > 0xFFFF:
            raise ValueError ("Invalid Profile Descriptor")
    for uuid in protocols:
        if not is_valid_uuid (uuid):
            raise ValueError ("invalid UUID specified in protocols")        

    try:
        _bt.sdp_advertise_service (sock._sock, name, service_id, \
                service_classes, profiles, provider, description, \
                protocols)
    except _bt.error as e:
        raise BluetoothError (str (e))
```

I'm can't print off the client information if I don't advertise, and get a null pointer exception on the android side, so I figure it's necessary, but can't get past this error if I do advertise.
This is the smallest amount of code I can have to get this error.  Like I mentioned, not advertising results in no error, but I can't print off client information on the connect (the android side can't find the pi).

If you do know of a way to do this without that portion, here's the android code:

```
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = BTAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            TextView textShowConnected = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textShowConnected);
            if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) 
            {
                for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) 
                {
                    if(device.getName().toString().equals("Pi"))
                    {
                        textShowConnected.setText("Found the Pi.  Address is "+device.getAddress());
                        TextView textShowConnectedSocket = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textShowConnectedSocket);
                        //textShowConnectedSocket.setText("uuid is: "+device.getUuids()[0].getUuid().toString());
                        try 
                        {
                            BluetoothSocket connection = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
                            //BluetoothSocket connection = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(device.getUuids()[0].getUuid());
                            connection.connect();
                            if(connection.isConnected())
                            {
                                textShowConnected.setText("Is connected from second.");
                                textShowConnectedSocket.setText("Is conencted to: "+connection.getRemoteDevice().getName().toString());
                                textShowPlace.setText("Is connected to: "+connection.getRemoteDevice().getAddress().toString());
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                textShowConnected.setText("No connection.");
                                textShowConnectedSocket.setText("No connection.");
                                textShowPlace.setText("No connection.");
                            }
                        } 
                        catch (IOException e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    //DeviceItem newDevice = new DeviceItem(device.getName(), device.getAddress(), "false");
                    //deviceItemList.add(newDevice);
                }
            }
        }
```

My most recent Java side attempt (just in case the pi side was fine):

```
for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) 
{
    if(device.getName().toString().equals("Pi"))
    {
        textShowConnected.setText("Found the Pi.  Address is "+device.getAddress());
        TextView textShowConnectedSocket = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textShowConnectedSocket);
        TextView textShowPlace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textShowPlace);
        //textShowConnectedSocket.setText("uuid is: "+device.getUuids()[0].getUuid().toString());
        int bt_port_to_connect = 1;
        BluetoothSocket deviceSocket = null;
        Method m = null;
        try {
            textShowPlace.setText("created socket");
            m = device.getClass().getMethod("createInsecureRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
            deviceSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device,bt_port_to_connect);
            deviceSocket.connect();
            if(deviceSocket.isConnected()) 
            {
                textShowPlace.setText("is connected");
                textShowConnectedSocket.setText("Connected successfully.");
                textShowConnected.setText("Connected to: "+deviceSocket.getRemoteDevice().getName().toString());
            }
            else
            {
                textShowConnectedSocket.setText("Did not connect.");
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            textShowPlace.setText("catch statement "+e);
            textShowConnectedSocket.setText("No connection.");
        } 
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e) 
        {
            textShowConnected.setText("No such method.");
            textShowPlace.setText("catch statement "+e);
        } 
        catch (InvocationTargetException e) 
        {
            textShowPlace.setText("catch statement "+e);
            textShowConnectedSocket.setText("No connection.");
        } 
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
        {
            textShowPlace.setText("catch statement "+e);
            textShowConnectedSocket.setText("No connection.");
        }
        //device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);                                                                            
        //device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    }
    //DeviceItem newDevice = new DeviceItem(device.getName(), device.getAddress(), "false");
    //deviceItemList.add(newDevice);
}
```

I'd appreciate any help on this with getting a connection going.  I'm not sure what's getting messed up here.

Answer (score 15):

Looks like to advertise it just needed: "sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan"

And to connect it needed bluetooth.PORT_ANY from that import, so I'm marking this as answered.

To anyone that finds this because of their own problems with this.  You have an answer now.  Good luck.

Comment: If this is insufficient, following from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675931/bluetooth-btcommon-bluetootherror-2-no-such-file-or-directory then using David's advice worked for me